# What does it mean by the colorful squares on left-side in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

> I did not get any answer while browsing, it might be because I am unable to search in a right manner.

[image]

Comment: Note what code is on those three lines

Comment: So some dart extension is doing that.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I am developing a mobile app using Flutter (dart)

Answer (score 1):

In file settings.json of VsCode do you can add the value: **"dart.flutterGutterIcons": true**,
this will set for squares left-side in your editor.

Answer (score 0):

The colorful squares are indicating the colors which we have chosen in our implementation.

[image]